# Full deck in Haskell using list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I'm quite new to Haskell (and programming).
My assignment is to define a function that returns a full deck of card (aka 52 cards). Trying to include my thought process in the notes next to  the code.

-- The values I've defined

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade  deriving (Show, Enum)

data Value = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven
          | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen
          | King | Ace  deriving (Show, Enum) 

type Card = (Suit, Value)  -- A card must have a suit and a value
type Deck = [Card]        -- A deck consists of a list of cards

fullDeck :: Deck    -- My function is supposed to consist of a deck
fullDeck = [(suit, value) | suit <- [Club..Spade], value <- [Two..Ace]]  -- Tried my luck using ''list comprehensions''. Is it necessary to type [Club..Spade] or does it work for just [Club..] as well?
```

My code won't load. The error I'm getting:

```
beginner.hs:11:62: error:
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (Two.. Ace)
   |
11 | fullDeck = [(suit, value) | suit <- [Club..Spade], value <- [Two..Ace]]
```

No matter how I try to solve it, some new error shows up, so I'm obviously doing some major fail(s) that I can't locate.

Also I'm curious on how to make sure that there will only be 52 cards in my deck, because at the moment my list consists of an infinite amount?

Comment: How did you get an infinite list for  `fullDeck` when the current definition isn't syntactically correct? Syntax error aside, that will result in a 52-card deck.

Comment: Not sure, I just assumed :D Mostly because I can't interpret why there would only be 52 cards, so I assumed I didn't  define an total sum for the deck :/

Comment: Nvm, now I understand... Because there's only 52 possibilities. God im dumb

Comment: "A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (Two.. Ace)" *means*, `Two..` was interpreted as the operator `(.)` from a module `Two`; then we're left with `.Ace` which is interpreted by the compiler to be the partial application `flip (.) Ace` in the *operator section* syntax thus it offers us to enclose it in parentheses, `( . Ace )`, or with full module import syntax `( Two.. Ace )`. A common Haskell gotcha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to use *spaces* between the data constructors (like `Club` and `Spade`) and the `..` operator. By failing to do so, Haskell sees this as dots that are used for for example *qualified* imports.

The following works:

```
[(suit, value) | suit <- [Club .. Spade], value <- [Two .. Ace]]
--                            ^  ^                     ^  ^
```

This generates the expected:

```
Prelude> [(suit, value) | suit <- [Club .. Spade], value <- [Two .. Ace]]
[(Club,Two),(Club,Three),(Club,Four),(Club,Five),(Club,Six),(Club,Seven),(Club,Eight),(Club,Nine),(Club,Ten),(Club,Jack),(Club,Queen),(Club,King),(Club,Ace),(Diamond,Two),(Diamond,Three),(Diamond,Four),(Diamond,Five),(Diamond,Six),(Diamond,Seven),(Diamond,Eight),(Diamond,Nine),(Diamond,Ten),(Diamond,Jack),(Diamond,Queen),(Diamond,King),(Diamond,Ace),(Heart,Two),(Heart,Three),(Heart,Four),(Heart,Five),(Heart,Six),(Heart,Seven),(Heart,Eight),(Heart,Nine),(Heart,Ten),(Heart,Jack),(Heart,Queen),(Heart,King),(Heart,Ace),(Spade,Two),(Spade,Three),(Spade,Four),(Spade,Five),(Spade,Six),(Spade,Seven),(Spade,Eight),(Spade,Nine),(Spade,Ten),(Spade,Jack),(Spade,Queen),(Spade,King),(Spade,Ace)]
```

We can also - like @Amalloy says - make the types `Bounded`, and then write it like:

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade  deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)

data Value = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven
          | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen
          | King | Ace  deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)

fullDeck :: Deck    -- My function is supposed to consist of a deck
fullDeck = [(suit, value) | suit <- [minBound ..], value <- [minBound ..]]
```

or we could define a helper value:

```
boundedAll :: (Bounded a, Ord a) => [a]
boundedAll = [minBound ..]
```

and then write it like:

```
fullDeck :: Deck
fullDeck = (,) <$> boundedAll <*> boundedAll
```

Comment: Incidentally, why is there not some polymorphic "all the things" defined as `[minBound..] :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => [a]`? This seems like a frequently useful idea, and here if it existed we could just write `fullDeck :: Deck; fullDeck = (,) <$> allTheThings <*> allTheThings` (after deriving Bounded for Suit and Value).